# SQL multiple joins SELECT query with MAX()

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

The following query select the subforums from the database and the last posts in each one of them.

```
SELECT
    forums.*,
    MAX(posts.id),
    posts.title AS lastmsgtitle,
    posts.timee AS lastmsgtime,
    posts.useraid AS lastmsguseraid,
    posts.useradn AS lastmsguseradn,
    users.photo AS lastmsgphoto
FROM forums
    LEFT JOIN posts
        ON(posts.forumid = forums.id)
    LEFT JOIN users
        ON(posts.useraid = users.id)
WHERE forums.relatedto='$forumid'
    and posts.type='post'
GROUP BY forums.id
ORDER BY `id` DESC
```

The only problem, the query not select the last post, any ideas why?

FORUMS [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xL7pG.png)

POSTS [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6oDD0.png)

Comment: You may want to include your data sample as well. __ If the last post does not have matching rows in FORUMS, it will not be included since your OUTER JOIN is LEFT.

Comment: Incidentally although mysql will allow you to do group by only id, it is not a good idea. Your results will be somewhat unpredictable. You should never group by unless you include all columns in the query which are not aggregate fields. Break this bad habit now. And while you are at it stop using the SQL antipattern of select *.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using a subquery to select the `max(id)` for each post.

```
SELECT
    f.*,  -- replace the f.* with the columns that you need to return
    p1.MaxId,
    p2.title AS lastmsgtitle,
    p2.timee AS lastmsgtime,
    p2.useraid AS lastmsguseraid,
    p2.useradn AS lastmsguseradn,
    u.photo AS lastmsgphoto
FROM forums f
LEFT JOIN
(
    select MAX(id) MaxId, forumid
    from posts
    group by forumid
) p1
    ON p1.forumid = f.id
LEFT JOIN posts p2
    ON p2.forumid = f.id
    and p1.MaxId = p2.id
    and p2.type='post'
LEFT JOIN users u
    ON p2.useraid = u.id
WHERE f.relatedto='$forumid'
ORDER BY `id` DESC
```

Comment: the only problem that if a messege in subforum never posted, he doesn't shows.

Comment: @user2124281 your original post, please edit with some sample data for each table and the desired result from the query.

Comment: @user2124281 Unfortunately, images of your tables is not very helpful.  Can you edit your post with some sample data and then the desired result?

Comment: @bluefeet: You probably need to move the `p2.type='post'` condition from the `WHERE` to `ON` clause, to keep with the OP's requirements (about posts without subforum messages).